# How to limit the text in a label using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

I am getting text from the database to the label in a repeater. the text from the database is huge. I want it limit to only 3 lines...

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("JobDescription")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
<asp:Label CssClass="ShortDesc" Text='<%# Eval("JobDescription")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

CSS

```
.ShortDesc
{
   height:50px;
   Overflow:hidden;
}
```

OR restrict to 200 or N characters

```
<asp:Label CssClass="ShortDesc" Text='<%# Eval("JobDescription").ToString().SubString(0,Math.Min(200,Eval("JobDescription").ToString().Length)) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

OR return a Short Desc from your DB

```
SELECT substring(JobDescription,1,200)+'...' AS ShortJobDescription, JobDescription From Jobs
```

And use that in your repeater

```
<asp:Label CssClass="ShortDesc" Text='<%# Eval("ShortJobDescription")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to style the label. Limit the height of the element and set the overflow to none.

Comment: <asp:Label style="overflow: no-display; height: 10px" Text='<%# Eval("JobDescription")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>  i Tried like this no luck not workiong

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch some specific number of characters from database, using sql query if you are using sql server as a database like 25 characters without breaking sentence as follows:

```
  SELECT LEFT(LEFT(column_name, 25), LEN(LEFT(column_name, 25)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(column_name, 25)))) FROM tbl_Name
```

above query will return first 25 characters without breaking sentence.you can modify query by replacing 25 for as much as characters you want to assign text for label.

Comment: by using css this will break the sentence in between and will show wrong words like rather than showing complete text as database this will show databa only as it can break the sentence its better to get complete word from sql it self.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="fileName" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("fileName") %>' Text='<%# Eval("fileName") %>' ></asp:Label>
  </ ItemTemplate >
  <ItemStyle Width="35%" CssClass="fontWeight limitWidth"/>
 }

Inn .css
.limitWidth {
 white-space: nowrap;     
 max-width: 100px;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap the label in a div and apply css:

```
  <div class="labelLimit">
     <asp:Label  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Body") %>' ></asp:Label>
   </div>


.labelLimit{
   height:120px;
   Overflow:hidden;    
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```